# flex layout not working with md-dialog-actions

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angularjs-material

I need to open a modal on button click for which i am using angular material.
where i need two buttons at the bottom of a dialog towards right .
I used layout with flex which is not working as required.

Html:

```
<md-dialog ng-cloak class="promptIncludeExclude-options">
<md-toolbar class="promptIncludeExclude-header">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span class="title">Product Inclusion Notification</span>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="dialogController.closeDialog()">
            <span class="close-dialog">&#10005;</span>
        </md-button>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog-content>
<md-dialog-actions layout="row">
    <div flex="25" flex-offset="25"><md-button ng-click="dialogController.closeDialog()" >Proceed</md-button></div>
    <div flex="50" flex-offset="20" ><md-button ng-click="dialogController.closeDialog()">Cancel</md-button></div>
</md-dialog-actions>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please explain what you mean by what is required and post the relevant CSS. It's impossible to answer your question as it is.

Comment: Would you please add a bit more information about your requirements? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple layout configuration. Use the layout classes to align the content as you want:

```
<md-dialog-actions class="layout-row layout-align-end-end">
    <md-button ng-click="dialogController.closeDialog()">Proceed</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="dialogController.closeDialog()">Cancel</md-button>
</md-dialog-actions>
```

It's not necessary wrapping the buttons inside divs and giving them flex width and offset, and for sure this is what is messing things...

Comment: thanks you, for this information. For information : in `md-dialog-content` is the same `<div layout="row"></div>` **not working**, just use element `<div class="layout-row"><div class="flex-50"></div><..></..></div>`, **with classes names it's work nicely**